# Should be the solution of Arithmetic differential equation an arithmetic function?

Tags: number-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, modular-arithmetic

Arithmitic function is a real or complex valued function  ‎$f(n) ‎$ defined on the set of natural numbers (i.e positive integers) that expresses some arithmetical property of  ‎$n ‎$, we cite as examples: divisor function and Euler totiont function  ‎$\cdots‎$ , I w'd like to know if there is an example of arithmitic function which present a solution for Arithmitic differential equation. Then my question here is:

> > **Question**:  Should be the solution of Arithmetic differential equation an arethmitic function?
>
> **Note:** For example the solution of this arithmitic differential equation: $\zeta^{.}+\zeta=0$ ,is it arithmitic function? Is it algebraic function?

Comment: 1. The word is "arithmetic", not "arithmitic".  2. What is an "arithmetic differential equation"?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Yes , Ordinary differential equation which replace function by integer number and for example :the derivative operator which can be  replaced by a “Fermat quotient operator”

Comment: A-R-I-T-H-M-E-T-I-C. But maybe you should stick to one replacement for the derivative operator, and define that replacement precisely, and then you may have a question someone could answer.

Comment: Gone away again?

Comment: I don't think that the *arithmetic function* as you defined is the correct thing to think about. In fact, as far as I understand about arithmetic differential equations, you should think of $\mathbb Z$ as an analog of $\mathbb C[z]$, i.e., $\mathbb Z$ is itself considered as a ring of "functions", and we define the derivative on it. A solution of an arithmetic differential equation should lie in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This should be about Buium's arithmetic differential equation. References could be consulted at a website of [a course](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~borger/classes/copenhagen-2016/index.html).